# Argparse using function from another file within that file

Tags: python-2.7, function, argparse, subparsers

I have two classes:

```
OptionParser
```

```
Application
```

stored in separate files (option_parser.py and application.py). The former defines how command line input should be handled. The latter imports the former, reads the user input, and carries on with the request.

How do I call a method defined in application.py's Application without importing it inside option_parser.py (as that would lead to an infinite loop, since application.py imports OptionParser from option_parser.py). If I use `set_defaults(func=method_name)`, then I am told that global function `method_name` is not defined in that scope.

I already have a workaround for this, but it just doesn't seem right:

```
if self.options.action == 'tags':
    self.list_tags()
elif self.options.action == 'branches':
    self.list_branches()
```

I've tried to find the answer in the official documentation, Google, and on SO -  to no avail.

Comment: What seems wrong about that?

Comment: It doesn't seem like correct solution. I'd like to be able to use:
`self.options.func()`

Comment: Could you give some more context - that seems like a very close coupling between the argument parsing and your class, which will make both harder to test.

Comment: One other workaround I've been thinking about was to split the code into three files/classes: OptionParser, Application and Wrapper. 

Wrapper would import OptionParser and Application, OptionParser would import Application (so that Application's method can be supplied to `set_defaults(func=)`, and Application would not import OptionParser (instead, the instance of the class would be passed as an argument).

Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. Again, give more context; [edit] the question to give a less abstract demonstration of the functionality you're working on.

Comment: Perhaps the coupling is too close. The problem is that I am refactoring a toolset, and I am currently translating tools that have been written in Bash (developer A) to Python so that all tools are within the same framework (developer B).

Refactoring the framework itself is probably not an option (at least for the time being). But it is still much better than the tools written in Bash.

Comment: Added less abstract context.

Comment: That's made things, if anything, less clear. You appear to have an instance method pretending to be a class method, for one. The code won't run, it's not a [mcve]. Perhaps, if you have working code that you think could be generally improved, it would be better suited to [codereview.se]? Note that they will require full code in context and will review with a broader remit than the single block you've highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using `set_defaults(func=method_name)` with a subparser as illustrated in the `argparse` docs?  That's an easy way of invoking a function.  It takes advantage of flexibility built into defining defaults and setting attributes in the `args` namespace.  But there's no code devoted to this feature.

> Associating functions with actions like this is typically the easiest way to handle the different actions for each of your subparsers. However, if it is necessary to check the name of the subparser that was invoked, the dest keyword argument to the add_subparsers() call will work:

That 2nd sentence is giving you permission to use

```
if self.options.action == 'tags'
```

In your case `set_defaults` is not the easiest way.

`argparse` is primarily a means of finding out what your user wants.  It isn't meant to be a dispatcher.  Usually that's the responsibility of your code.

My impression from other `argparse` questions is that most of the time programmers don't use this `set_defaults` option.  A search of SO for `[argparse] set_default` only turns up 37 posts (answers or questions) (compared to 1.5K questions for just the argparse tag).

---

Here's a working script that implements my idea of passing `set_defaults` values to an `parser` setup function.  It's one file, but the `parser` part could just as well be imported.

```
import argparse

def make_parser(defaults):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmdstr')
    sp.required = True
    for key in defaults:
        spp = sp.add_parser(key)
        spp.set_defaults(cmd=defaults[key])
    return parser

def foo(args):
    print('foo')

def bar(args):
    print('bar')

if __name__=='__main__':
    dd = {'cmd1': foo, 'cmd2': bar}
    parser = make_parser(dd)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    args.cmd(args)
```

Sample calls:

```
0930:~/mypy$ python3 stack42897689.py cmd1
Namespace(cmd=<function foo at 0xb70c2dac>, cmdstr='cmd1')
foo
0931:~/mypy$ python3 stack42897689.py cmd2
Namespace(cmd=<function bar at 0xb7145614>, cmdstr='cmd2')
bar
```

With this `dd` dictionary, I could just as easily have done the dispatching with:

```
dd[args.cmdstr](None)
```

The basic goal is to pair up a commandline string with a function call.  `set_defaults` is one way to do within `argparse`.  But dictionary like `dd` is also widely used in Python code.  And so are `if/else` statements.

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess I will have to be content with the "workaround" solution, then.

Comment: BTW, the reason is that I wanted to avoid using conditional statement blocks, and instead resort to calling correct function right away.

Comment: You could pass functions from the main to the imported module via function call parameters.  I added a crude sketch to my answer.  Details will have to wait.

Comment: Hm, I will consider that. Thank you. Not sure code reviewers will not frown upon this, but this is certainly something worth inspecting.